# Can I use the distributive law to pull this term out of a double summation?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation

In *Concrete Mathematics*, Graham Knuth, and Patashnik use the notation $[P(x)]$ to denote $1$ if $P(x)$ is true and $0$ if $P(x)$ is false, which lets you write the sum

$$\sum_{1\leq k \leq n} a_k$$

as

$$\sum_k a_k[1\leq k \leq n]$$
which sums over all integers $k$, but only "counts" those in the desired range. But I get confused once multiple indices are involved. is this reasoning valid?
\begin{align}
\sum_{1\leq j\leq k \leq n} a_ja_k &= \sum_{j,k} a_ja_k[1\leq j \leq k \leq n] \\
&= \sum_{j,k} a_ja_k[1\leq j \leq n][j\leq k \leq n]\\
&= \sum_j\left(\sum_k a_ja_k [1\leq j \leq n][j\leq k \leq n]\right)\\
&= \sum_j \left(a_j[1\leq j\leq n]\sum_k a_k [j\leq k \leq n]\right)\\
&= \sum_{1\leq j \leq n} \left(a_j\sum_{j\leq k\leq n} a_k\right)
\end{align}
I'm specifically wondering about the second-to-last equality. The book says you can use the distributive law to pull a term out of a sum as long as the term doesn't "depend on the index of the sum". In the second to last equality, I'm pulling out the term $a_j[1\leq j \leq n]$ from the inner sum. The index variable (I hope that's the right name for it) of the inner sum is $k$ and the term I'm pulling out doesnt contain $k$. But the lower bound for the inner sum is $j$ and the term I'm pulling out *does* contain a $j$. So is this legal?

Comment: It is totally legal. The point of the $[1\le j\le n]$ notation is that the inner sum does not have any bounds any more.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Oh yeah, that makes sense, thank you so much! (if you make this an answer, i'll accept it btw)

Comment: What is not allowed is to distribute out a term that depends on the *index* of summation.  A term merely involving a bound (upper or lower limit) of a sum is okay to factor out.